# How to use scipy minimize with fixed constants

Tags: python, scipy

I have a really basic question. I would like to use scipy.minimize but with some constants fixed. Here is a toy example that doesn't work but which shows what I would like to achieve:

```
import scipy.optimize

def error(a, b, guess):
    target = 4
    return abs(a*guess - b*target)

a = 2
b = 3
calculated = scipy.optimize.minimize(error, (a, b, 0,))
print(calculated.x)
```

In my real code `a` and `b` are calculated in the main body so I can't hard code them into the `error` function.

How do you use minimize with fixed constants such as in this example?

---

It was suggested to use args. Here is my failed attempt:

```
import scipy.optimize

def error(x, b, c, n):
    return abs(c*b**x - n * 2**n)

n = 10
c = 1.1547
b = 1.6875
x = 10

calculated = scipy.optimize.minimize(error, 5, args=(b,c,n))
print(calculated.x)
```

This just returns `[5.]` which is not the optimum.

Comment: Pass them using ```args```.

Comment: @sascha Could you give an example please?

Comment: Read scipy's [user-guide](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/tutorial/optimize.html). There are many examples.

Comment: @sascha I tried to use args but it still doesn't work https://bpaste.net/show/1cffac1ff8f3

Comment: It doesn't work is not an error-description. And external code-links are pretty uncool, given that you could edit your question providing new information.

Comment: @sascha sorry yes. It just outputs 5.

Comment: Make sure you understand the basic optimization-theory. In this regard: convexity & (only) the guarantee of some local-optimium and the assumption of being differentiable twice (by the solver used in your case; although not explicitly chosen): abs is not!. scipy.minimize is not a silver-bullet! Care is needed! And i did not even mention numerical-stability, which is often problematic for things like exponentials like in your case, especially without any bounding.

Comment: "How do you use minimize with fixed constants such as in this example?" is answered by using args, but that has nothing to do with why your second example isn't returning the answer you want.  If you reuse the same function (with the arguments reordered as you did in the args case), it should work fine.

Comment: @DSM That's very interesting thank you.  I had no idea I had two different problems!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `lambda` function to create a new function that fixes the constants: your first example becomes:

```
import scipy.optimize

def error(a, b, guess):
    target = 4
    return abs(a*guess - b*target)

a = 2
b = 3
calculated = scipy.optimize.minimize(lambda guess: error(a, b, guess), 0)
```

`calculated.x` returns 6, as expected. Thanks to the other commenters for pointing out `args`, that's interesting, but I've always used this `lambda` approach.

Comment: That's a very nice and elegant solution, thank you.